# Showing two images with the same colorbar in log

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, plot

I have two sparse matrices "Matrix1" and "Matrix2" of the same size `p x n`.

By sparse matrix I mean that it contains a lot of exactly zero elements.

I want to show the two matrices under the same colormap and a unique colorbar. Doing this in MATLAB is straightforward:

```
bottom = min(min(min(Matrix1)),min(min(Matrix2)));
top  = max(max(max(Matrix1)),max(max(Matrix2)));
subplot(1,2,1)
imagesc(Matrix1)
colormap(gray)
caxis manual
caxis([bottom top]);
subplot(1,2,2)
imagesc(Matrix2)
colormap(gray)
caxis manual
caxis([bottom top]);
colorbar;
```

**My problem:**

In fact, when I show the matrix using `imagesc(Matrix)`, it can ignore the noises (or backgrounds) that always appear with using  `imagesc(10*log10(Matrix))`.

That is why, I want to show the `10*log10` of the matrices. But in this case, the minimum value will be `-Inf` since the matrices are sparse. In this case `caxis` will give an error because bottom is equal to `-Inf`.

What do you suggest me? How can I modify the above code?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very important point is that the minimum value in your matrix will always be `0`.  Leveraging this, a very simple way to address your problem is to add `1` inside the log operation so that values that map to `0` in the original matrix also map to `0` in the `log` operation.  This avoids the `-Inf` error that you're encountering.  In fact, this is a very common way of visualizing the Fourier Transform if you will.  Adding `1` to the logarithm ensures that the transform has no negative values in the output, yet the derivative or its rate of change remains intact as the effect is simply a translation of the curve by `1` unit to the left.

Therefore, simply do `imagesc(10*log10(1 + Matrix));`, then the minimum is always bounded at `0` while the maximum is unbounded but subject to the largest value that is seen in `Matrix`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)